# Mapeamento OneToMany Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Olá,

Em uma aplicação tem uma classe que eu preciso fazer um mapeamento OneToMany, essa classe pai ficara responsavel por realizar a persisntecia da classe filha. A minha duvida é, eu fiz o mapeamento da Bag na classe pai conforme abaixo:

```
        Bag(x => x.ItensMovimentacaoBanco, x =>
        {
            x.Cascade(Cascade.Persist);
            x.Key(y =>
            {
                y.Column("MovimentacaoBancoId");
                y.NotNullable(true);
            });
            x.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);
        }, x => x.OneToMany());
```

Agora eu também preciso fazer o mapeamento ManyToOne na classe filho?

Comment: Sim, precisa, até por uma questão de que é o recomendado para o *framework*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta é sim, conforme comentário e esse link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/dec6171d-6046-4ab8-8a4c-ea1cd5b307cf/mapeamento-onetomany-nhibernate?forum=mvcpt